# How to activate mouseleave, if it has been x amount of time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I've got this type of situation, but I only want to "Do something" if the user "mouseleave(s)" for more than x amount of time, say one second. How should I implement that?

```
$("#someElement, #someOtherElement").mouseleave(function() {
   // Do something.
});
```

Later I added:

```
    $('.popover3-test').popover({
        placement:'bottom',
        template: $('.popover2'),
        trigger: 'manual',

        }).mouseenter(function(e) {
        $(this).popover('show');

        $(".popover3-test, .popover2").each(function() {
            var t = null;

            $(this)
                .mouseleave(function() {
                    t = setTimeout(function() {
                        $('.popover2').hide();
                    }, 1000); // Or however many milliseconds
                })
                .mouseenter(function() {
                    if(t !== null)
                        clearTimeout(t);
                })
            ;
        });


});
```

Comment: What have you tried? And how do you mean exactly - does the time start FROM the point of mouse leave, until some other event? And if so, what is that event?

Answer (score 5):

`setTimeout` should do the trick:

```
$("#someElement, #someOtherElement").each(function() {
    var t = null;

    $(this)
        .mouseleave(function() {
            t = setTimeout(function() {
                // Do something.
            }, 1000); // Or however many milliseconds
        })
        .mouseenter(function() {
            if(t !== null) {
                clearTimeout(t);
                t = null;
            }
        })
    ;
});
```

EDIT: If you want it to work on either, just remove the `.each`:

```
var t = null;

$("#someElement, #someOtherElement")
    .mouseleave(function() {
        t = setTimeout(function() {
            // Do something.
        }, 1000); // Or however many milliseconds
    })
    .mouseenter(function() {
        if(t !== null) {
            clearTimeout(t);
            t = null;
        }
    })
;
```

Comment: ++ 1 indeed, for you! and letting me know what I missed, `:)`

Comment: Thanks a bunch, but it seems to "do something," in this case hide the popover, after 1000, when i move the mouse from #element1 to #element2. It could be a problem with my code, which i will put in my question.

Comment: okay, getting closer, it works perfectly the first time, on reload, but then it doesn't after that. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @watson: On *reload*? That is really odd. Can you post a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or an example page, please?

Comment: @watson: I have no clue :( I'll look at it tomorrow, maybe it'll be clearer :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#someElement, #someOtherElement").bind('mouseenter mouseleave', (function() {

    var timer;

    return function (e) {

       if(e.type === 'mouseleave') {
          timer = setTimeout(function () {
             //do something
          }, 1000);
       }  else {
          clearTimeout(timer);
       }

    };

}()));
```

**EDIT** - usable on multiple elements

```
$("#someElement, #someOtherElement").bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function (e) {

       var timer = $(this).data('timer');

       if(e.type === 'mouseleave') {
          timer = setTimeout(function () {
             //do something
          }, 1000);
       }  else {
          clearTimeout(timer);
       }

       $(this).data('timer', timer);    
    };

});
```

Comment: `setInterval`? I think you meant `setTimeout`. Probably.

Comment: This suffers from the same problem as minitech's, they only work once on reload, then it doesn't work when you mouse from element1 to element2.

Comment: watson, I fixed it for you so that each element uses its own timer.

Answer (score 2):

this might not work as is, but gives you some ideas...

```
var elapsed = 0;
var timer = setInterval(function(){
  elapsed += 20;
  if( elapsed >= 1000 ) {
     doSomething();
     clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, 20 );
$('#some').mouseleave(timer);
$('#some').mouseenter(function(){clearInterval(timer);elapsed=0;});
```

Comment: i actually just didnt think of the clearTimeout. but i like the way mine reads